# Laravel 5.1 select only rows which do not belong to user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a role based application which has `timesheets`, `supervisors` and `users`.

Timesheets belong to `users`.

Users are assigned to `supervisors` and therefore `supervisors` are able to approve users timesheets who they are assigned to.

The problem is that `supervisors` can also submit their own timesheets.

I want to be able to select timesheets that are assigned to the supervisor but do not belong to the supervisor (i.e they didn't submit the timesheet).

I have the following model relationship setup:

```
/**
 * The user that owns the timesheet.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User\User');
}

/**
 * The supervisor that approved the timesheet.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function supervisor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User\User');
}
```

The code I have at the moment is:

```
$this->timesheet->whereHas('user.supervisors', function ($query) {
    $query->where('timesheet.status', 'Submitted');
})->get();
```

But the above code, also selects timesheets that the supervisor submitted themselves as well as ones they are assigned to.

I have tried the following code to only get timesheets that are assigned to the supervisor...

```
$this->timesheet->whereHas('user.supervisors', function ($query) {
    $query->where('timesheet.status', 'Submitted');
    $query->where('user.supervisors.id', '<>', 'timesheet.user_id');
})->get();
```

...however, the above code throws an error;

> [2016-04-12 11:45:15] local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.supervisors.id' in 'where clause'' in /home/vagrant/Code/App/public/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:319

How can I achieve what I need?

Comment: The first thing that I notice in your code is the 'user.supervisors.id' that (I think) is wrong: shouldn't it be 'user.supervisor_id' instead? Another important thing to clarify is about the data you want to retrieve: you want to get the timesheets that does NOT belong to the actually logged in supervisor?

Comment: I'm not sure I am tackling the problem using the `$query->where('user.supervisors.id', '<>', 'timesheet.user_id');` anyway.  My problem is that this is a scheduled job so the supervisor is not logged in anyway.  The script just gets a list of all timesheets that are awaiting approval and then sends a list of timesheets that the supervisor needs to approve (but I do not wish to include their own timesheet, if this makes sense).